# it cleft-constructions

Tags: cleft-constructions

> Fabricius was the first to discover the valves of the veins.

If I change this sentence into It-cleft sentences, have four answers.

> 1. It was Fabricius who was the first to discover the valves of the veins.
> 2. It was the first to discover the valves of the veins that was Fabricius.
> 3. It was to discover the valves of the veins that Fabrious was the first.
> 4. It was the valves of the veins that Fabrious was the first to discover.

I want to know if there can be other sentences for it-cleft sentences.

Comment: 2 and 3 don't seem correct.

Comment: Why so? Explain me.